# Apple Instruments has mangled symbols and greyed out symbol names when profiling C++ application

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, profiling, instruments

I'm trying to profile a large C++ application with Apple Instruments. I also wanted to do it **WITHOUT** building an Xcode project/workspace around my project (since I have an insane amount of dependencies / libraries / makefiles already set up).

To do this I launched Instruments from `Xcode/Contents/Applications/Instruments` and selected a time profiler. For my target, I set it to my binary I wanted to profile. I then set the working directory to where my project files are (and the subsequent dSYM files are in a folder under that directory). I added the relevant arguments to my program and then hit the record button.

Now it records the run successfully and I can see that my program executed correctly in the console portion. But, under my symbols where I am supposed to see functions and lines of code are mangled values of those symbols that are greyed out. It looks like this:

[image: Instruments output]

I read online that this is because it can't find my symbol library for the specific application. This dSYM file for my application is located in `/working_directory/bin/application.dSYM`. So I went to `File -> Symbols` and this shows up:
[image: Symbols menu]

So I clicked on the `sh` icon and located `application.dSYM`. However when selected, I get an error stating: `No new libraries to symbolicate: The specified path didn't locate a dSYM for any of the selected libraries.`

I'm not really sure how I can set up my code so that Instruments can read the symbols?

Comment: Hello, did you find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Those aren't "mangled values", they're memory addresses.

Comment: When you compile any C++ code, all internal symbols are dropped and replaced with addresses. Try building with a debug flag