# Missing symbol names while profiling in Instruments 7

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, missing-symbols

I don't see any symbol names when I'm profiling application for iOS 8.

If I run profiler on simulator with iOS 9 everything works fine. Then I close instruments and switch to simulator with iOS 8.4 and I can see only hexadecimal addresses which reference to assembler or 'unavailable' content. Other threads are unnamed and everything, including system names are shown as binary pointers.

[image]

Instruments can't find dSYM file, so I tryied to re-symbolicate app as **File ▸ Symbols...** then I select missing symbols and there is option to locate dSYM file.

[image]

After select dSYM file, I get this message.

[image]

And it's over. I also tryied restart PC, rebuild application, clean project, delete Derived Data, reopen XCode and Instruments, reindexing files [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112394/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-app-in-instruments) but it has no effect.

Thanks.

PS: There is similar [post without solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683690/apple-instruments-has-mangled-symbols-and-greyed-out-symbol-names-when-profiling)

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: No. I didn't find any solution, I gave up and worked without instruments. I don't know if new versions of XCode (Instruments too) solves this problem, I didn't worked with that. If you have latest version and problem remains, it's still open question.

Comment: @eSeverus i have this same problem, did you find a solution ? 

you, were able to do the profiling on iOS 9 , so why do you insist on running profiling on iOS 8 ?

Comment: @EF No, I haven't find solution, because I don't work on this anymore. I was working on application that was about 3-4 times slower on iOS 8 than 9. Thanks to this bug, or whatever it is, I have never figured out why. Question is still open.